# Group users by age

Tags: postgresql

How could I create a SQL query that groups the users from a table into age groups of '[0-10]', '[11-20]', '[21-30]', '[31-40]', '[41-50]', '[51-60]', and '[61+]' with this formatting based on a column that directly says their age (not a date when they were born). The query should count the number of users in each "Age Group" and display the results in ascending order based on the "Age Group".

Answer (score 2):

A case statement will do this. Something like:

```
select 
case when age<=10 then "[0-10]"
when age<=20 then "[11-20]"
...
when age>=61 then "[61+]"
end as "Age Group",
count(distinct user_id)
from your_table_name
group by 
case when age<=10 then "[0-10]"
when age<=20 then "[11-20]"
...
when age>=61 then "[61+]"
end
```

Where the ... is the continuation of the age groups.

Comment: It did work! Thank you! The only think I edited was that inside count I put age - COUNT(age) and it gave me the desired result.

Comment: @ddoch003 It depends on what your table has (I wasn't sure what columns were there) if you only have one row per user then that would work, otherwise you could be over counting. Hopefully your table is just one row per user though and its all fine :) if there is a unique identifier for your users you can check this by doing select count(*),count(distinct user_id) from your_table_name and seeing if the two match - if they do then you only have one row per user.